# Registering Excel on iPad, when iTunes and Microsoft account emails differ?

Tags: ipad, ms-office

I have an Office 365 Home Premium subscription, and so I wish to use the subscription-based features of Excel for iPad.

The problem is that I use different email addresses for my iTunes and Office 365 subscriptions.

This is the series of steps I've followed:

1. Install Excel for iPad
2. Run Excel for iPad
3. Select "Buy Office 365 Home"
4. Select the tiny "I Already Have a Subscription"
5. Enter my iTunes Store password, for my iTunes email address

I then get the error message:

> "No Subscription
>    This Apple ID doesn't have a paid Office 365 subscription."

For my two different email addresses, the domain names are the same, but the account names are specific to the two products - as an anti-spam measure, and to make it easier to detect phishing messages.

I considered changing my Apple email address to be my Microsoft one, or my Microsoft email address to be my Apple one. But in both cases, I would have a large number of login details to change, on multiple programs on multiple devices.

**Are there any other alternative solutions, such as adding a second email address to either my iTunes or Microsoft accounts?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After days of looking, I've found the answer, via 
[Having Problems Activating Office for iPad? Here’s a Simple Solution](http://windowsitpro.com/office-365/having-problems-activating-office-ipad-here-s-simple-solution)

Briefly:

- Instead of saying “I already have a subscription”, choose the Read-only option
- Then click on the **Activate** button at lower-left
- Then you have an option to activate by using your Microsoft Office 365 account credentials

For me, doing this in Excel also activated my Word and PowerPoint iOS apps.

Comment: I don't even get the "Activate" link. I still have "Go Premium" and it never changes. As such all of the responses of this ilk are useless to me. The number of "closed" issues nothing to see here for this bug is disturbing.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had the same issue with my computer. I wasted my time on it for

many days but finally I got a solution from this link

http://www.microsoftliveassist.com/activation-problems-with-office-365/﻿﻿